# How can I show minimum day ticks on a years timescale in d3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have a d3 chart same as http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367

If I select a very short time span then it show 6am 9pm 12pm and so on..(Is it possible not to show less than a days interval?)

Is it possible to make a minimum interval to 1 day so it does not show 1am 2pm 6pm lables,?

I have data for each day so I dont want to show 6am 9pm and so on,

OR

If I fix the date format using

```
.tickFormat(d3.time.format("%d %b"))
.ticks(d3.time.days, 1)
```

The problem is If we have only few days data it displays fine. But if we have a years data the x axis will have 365 lables.
I just want to display date in same format always with minimum xaxis lables.

Sorry for my bad english, Hope you understood the problem

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [Custom time axis](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4149176).

In your case, you can stop at the `day` level:

```
var customTimeFormat = timeFormat([
  [d3.time.format("%Y"), function() { return true; }],
  [d3.time.format("%B"), function(d) { return d.getMonth(); }],
  [d3.time.format("%b %d"), function(d) { return d.getDate() != 1; }],
  [d3.time.format("%a %d"), function(d) { return d.getDay() && d.getDate() != 1; }],
]);
```

Comment: We still get duplicate day entries in this case (wed 15, wed 15) repeated.